# Show native camera roll exaclty with PhoneGAP (cordova) for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing web app for iOS7 platform with PhoneGap and camera plugin. I want use camera roll with button for turn on capture-view(like as native picker or as facebook photo-mode). 
I'm using Cordova Camera API and camera roll looks like otherwise(only photo/video, not button for turn on capture mode). I have read all documentation about plugin and tried use different set of options, but can't find solution.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';
    largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

function getPhoto(source) {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
<img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like the Camera plugin has the option to either grab a picture from the Camera itself, or the photo library: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#camerapicturesourcetype--enum